# Is it possible to degrade a NamingContainer in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Recently, a changement from PrimeFaces has made TabView became a NamingContainer, hence the component-path in the existing sources are broken.

For example:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView1">
    <p:dataTable id="table1">
        ...
```

Previously, the component path of the data table is `:table1`, but now it is `:tabView1:table1`.

Is it possible to degrade the tabView1 to a non-NamingContainer? I have tried to remove the id:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:dataTable id="table1">
        ...
```

So I can reference table1 with the old path `:table1`, Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about the change in PrimeFaces 3 **beta** version M3? Well, you shouldn't be surprised about that when you're working with a beta library. I peeked a bit round in the taglib.xml, but I don't see any `prependId` attribute like as the `<h:form>` has. So it probably just stops here. Best what you can do is to post a feature request to add a `prependId` attribute which you could set to `false`.